# Redirect without Auth Component

Tags: cakephp-2.2

Is there a way to redirect in cakephp without using the Auth component?
I don't have a database or a need for one so I do not have a users table to be able to instantiate the Auth component to use redirects. 
When I put a regular `header` redirect, it won't work because there is already an output to the page.

Cakephp 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redirect method of the controller:

```
class OrdersController extends AppController {

    public function add() {
      ...
      $this->redirect('/orders/thanks');
    }
```

I would do all necessary output for you. 
For more information see the CakePHP manual at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#flow-control

Comment: It's considered a good practice to use array notation for your route. i.e. $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'orders', 'action' => 'thanks'));

Comment: I have tried all variations of $this->redirect() and it simply does nothing, I just assumed it was a part of the auth controller. I should mention I am calling the redirect from within a plugin.